# Java Asynchronous Exceptions: Can I catch them?

Tags: java, exception, virtual-machine

I have been reading the JLS and I encountered the section [11.1.3. Asynchronous Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.3) from which I quote:

> Most exceptions occur synchronously as a result of an action by the
>   thread in which they occur, and at a point in the program that is
>   specified to possibly result in such an exception. An asynchronous
>   exception is, by contrast, an exception that can potentially occur at
>   any point in the execution of a program.

And

> Asynchronous exceptions occur only as a result of:
>
> [...]
>
> - An internal error or resource limitation in the Java virtual machine    that prevents it from implementing the semantics of the
>     Java    programming language. In this case, the asynchronous exception
>     that    is thrown is an instance of a subclass of VirtualMachineError.

Is it possible to catch such exceptions for logging purposes or notification (because I believe such thing is unrecoverable)? How can I achieve such thing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can catch such exceptions just like any other exception. The only problem is that they may occur at *any* place in your program, so catching them reliably is hard. You would basically have to wrap the `run` method of all threads and the `main` method in a `try..catch` block, but you can't do that for threads you don't control (like the Swing EDT, or threads for timers etc.).

Also catching any subclass of `Error` is usually not recommended, because the JVM may be in an unstable state, which might lead to a further failure (for example in the case of `OutOfMemoryError`, you might not even have enough memory to to the exception handling). However, logging would be a valid reason for catching `Error`s in my eyes.

My suggested solution would be to use an [uncaught exception handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) for this by [setting it as the default exception handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29). In this handler you will get all exceptions and errors, if they are not caught anywhere in the code, and you can try to log them.

Comment: And for any wondering if `try-catch` block can be inside a `try` block, yes you can have it. [Relevant code](http://ideone.com/stN75L).

Comment: @Prasanth Sure, `try..catch` can be everywhere a normal statement could be, this includes nested `try`. Of course you can also have a `try..catch` inside another `catch` for example.

Comment: I do not understand how adding a ```try..catch``` block helps catch such exceptions. i have such a case, and adding an 'inner' ```try--catch``` did not help my case. Could you elaborate? @Prasanth @Philipp Wendler?

Comment: @MichaelTrouw In this case the exception was probably thrown at a point when your thread was not inside the try block.

Comment: @PhilippWendler I just found out what was happening while debugging. The catch was never executed because the Exceptions were handled at a lower (library) level. i trashed those so they bubbled up as expected, and it seems it wasn't an async task anyway. Good tip for Java beginners, Exceptions 102: check if the Exception you expect actually gets thrown!

Answer (score 3):

There is no point of catching these exceptions (Subclasses of VirtualMachineError) as you have no indecattion in which state the pogram is at the point, the Doc saies about Virtual Machine Errors:

> A Java virtual machine implementation throws an object that is an
>   instance of a subclass of the class VirtualMethodError when an
>   internal error or resource limitation prevents it from implementing
>   the semantics described in this chapter. **This specification cannot
>   predict where internal errors or resource limitations may be
>   encountered and does not mandate precisely when they can be reported**.

so assuming you get in an OutOfMemoryError or an UnknownError there isnt much you can do about it, and once your vritualmashine doesnt work properly you cant provide the user anyhelp as your program isnt working properly as well, besides you have no idea at what time, point, and reason it happends since its not a code error that was caused from your program.